# print errors for multiple inputs if not correct - python

Tags: python

So I have this in my code

```
gender = raw_input('What is your gender? Male, Female or Other: ')
```

How would I make it print an error if they have not typed "Male", "Female" or "Other" when prompted to?

Comment: What do you mean by **print an error**? Raise an exception?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure you make it lower case so you don't have to deal with weird casing issues, and then you simply want to check your input against a collection of the words you are looking for. So your condition will use a `if not in`:

```
gender = input('What is your gender? Male, Female or Other: ')

if gender.lower() not in ("male", "female", "other"):
    print("you did a very bad thing! bad!")
```

If you are looking to raise an exception, then I suggest using the `ValueError` exception, using the same logic:

```
if gender.lower() not in ("male", "female", "other"):
    raise ValueError("You entered an incorrect input {}".format(gender))
```

Comment: Thank you! This is what I was looking for, with an extra tip with the '.lower()' I just added the continuous part from wtpoo's code!
I'm not too sure about the 'raise an exception' part. When I purposely typed an incorrect value I got this.
-- What is your gender? Male, Female or Other: asdas
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "blah.py", line 6, in <module>
    raise ValueError("You entered an incorrect input {}".format(gender))
ValueError: You entered an incorrect input asdas --

But anyway, thanks!! I just stuck with the print

Comment: @drizzyyy Yeah. Using the `raise` option, that is the expected output. I wasn't sure which error you were looking to output, so I proved both. Good luck with your work.

Answer (score 1):

Here's how you can print the error and make the user go again:

```
input = raw_input('What is your gender? Male, Female or Other: ').strip()
while input not in["Male", "Female" , "Other"]:
    print "Error! Go again!"
    input = raw_input('What is your gender? Male, Female or Other: ').strip() 
    if input not in["Male", "Female" , "Other"]: continue

print input
```

Comment: Thanks you! This helped me a lot, though I didn't use this exactly, I used "user go again" part from your code to idjaw's to get my end result!

Answer (score 0):

```
if gender not in ('Male', 'Female', 'Other'):
    print "Some Error message"
```

You can raise exception as well instead of print

Answer (score 0):

You make raise an exception (for example a `ValueError`) against a condition like below if you want.

```
 >>> if raw_input().lower() not in ['male','female','others']:
 ...     raise ValueError("Give a valid gender")
 ... 
 nothing
 Traceback (most recent call last):
   File "<stdin>", line 2, in <module>
 ValueError: Give a valid gender
```